# self.view.subviews empty in iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, xib, subview

I created custom UIViewController with xib and now I want to take first subview from it... it works on iOS 9, but on iOS 8 view.subviews has 0 views

```
let customVC = CustomViewController()
 
var customTestView = customVC.view.subviews.first
```

[image: 1]

self.view should have 1 subview in it

Comment: Verify, wether subview is initialized in iOS8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create the ViewController with xib,you should use this to init the ViewController

```
let vc =  CustomViewController(nibName: "nib", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
```